# ORACLE - GROUPING PARTIAL OUTPUT

Tags: sql, oracle, report, output, grouping

IF I HAVE TWO TABLES
**TABLE1** AND **TABLE2**

```
TABLE1
DEPTNO  EMPID
10       1
10       2
10       3

TABLE2
EMPID   PRJNAME
1       ABC
1       DEF
3       XYZ
```

THE QUERY

`SELECT T1.*,T2.PRJNAME
 FROM 
  TABLE1 T1, 
  TABLE2 T2 
 WHERE 
  T1.EMPID = T2.EMPID;`

WILL GIVE THE OUTPUT AS

```
DEPTNO  EMPID  PRJNAME
10       1      ABC
10       1      DEF
10       3      XYZ
```

HOW CAN THE QUERY BE MODIFIED TO OUTPUT THE RESULT AS

```
DEPTNO  EMPID  PRJNAME
10       1      ABC
                DEF
         3      XYZ
```

Comment: What are you using to generate your report? This is something that should be handled by your reporting tool, rather than in the SQL. It's possible to do it in SQL, but it would be better to get your reporting tool to handle it, since that's what they're designed to be able to do (in general).

Answer (score 1):

First, *never* use commas in the `from` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `join` syntax.

Second, SQL result sets are *unordered* sets.  Your result set seems to presume an ordering, but it doesn't have an `order by`.

I assume you intend:

```
select t1.*, t2.prjname
from table1 t1 join 
     table2 t2
     on t1.empid = T2.empid
order by t1.deptno, t1.empid, t2.prjname;
```

Then, you can do what you want using window functions:

```
select (case when lag(t1.deptno) over (partition by t1.deptno order by t1.empid, t2.prjname) is null
             then t1.deptno
        end) as deptno,
       (case when lag(t1.empid) over (partition by t1.deptno, t1.empid order by t2.prjname) is null
             then t1.empid
        end) as deptno,
       t2.prjname
from table1 t1 join 
     table2 t2
     on t1.empid = T2.empid
order by t1.deptno, t1.empid, t2.prjname;
```

Comment: The code need to be fixed. (1) replace `t2.projname` with **t2.prjname** (2) for the second CASE, replace `then t1.deptno
        end) as deptno` with **then t1.empid
        end) as empid**

Answer (score 0):

```
select      case row_number () over (partition by t1.deptno          order by t1.empid,t2.prjname)  when 1 then t1.deptno end       as deptno
           ,case row_number () over (partition by t1.deptno,t1.empid order by t2.prjname)           when 1 then t1.empid  end       as empid
           ,t2.prjname

from                    table1 t1 

            join        table2 t2 

            on          t1.empid = t2.empid

order by    t1.deptno
           ,t1.empid
           ,t2.prjname
;
```